# In Less, how to jump horizontally between search matches on the same line?

Tags: search, less, text, pager

On pressing <kbd>n</kbd>, Less skips all the search matches in the current line and moves to the next *line* with a match (even if the lines are wrapped). How can I make it move the cursor to all the matches in each line?

Comment: [Most](https://www.jedsoft.org/most/) with wrapped lines (`most -w`) has `n` stopping at each match. I'd still like to know if Less can do it.

Comment: Unless the file is huge, when `less` runs out of steam I switch to piping to vim: `command | vi -`.